# Convert flv video to 3gp

Tags: codecs, ffmpeg

I use winff (the GUI for ffmpeg) to convert audio/video to different formats. Yesterday I was trying to convert an flv video to 3gp (so that I could see it on my mobile phone), but it doesn't show the option to convert to 3gp. Are codecs missing in ffmpeg? Do I need to download such codecs from the repositories? Please, help.

Comment: Are you able to run this `ffmpeg -i infile.flv -s qcif -vcodec h263 -acodec libamr_nb -ac 1 -ar 8000 -r 25 -ab 12200 -y outfile.3gp` and get the proper output? Do you get any error message when you use winff?

Comment: Thanks for answering. When I run your code nothing happens, as shown.

Comment: williepabon@williepabon-VGN-N130G:~$ ffmpeg -i /home/williepabon/Downloads/Platypus In Sheep's Clothing.flv -s qcif -vcodec h263 -acodec libamr_nb -ac 1 -ar 8000 -r 25 -ab 12200 -y /home/williepabon/Downloads/Platypus.3gp
> 

Please note that ffmpeg (using the GUI, command mode is beyond my knowledge) works nice for other conversions I've made.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. Installed Mobile Media Converter which use ffmpeg and mencoder to do conversions. It also has a nice GUI. Thanks for the help.